# How to use ovirt_role module of ansible to provide all permits to user

Tags: ansible, kvm, ovirt

I'm using ovirt.ovirt.ovirt_role of ansible to create roles in RHV(Red hat Virtulization) environment. I need to create a role which will provide all permissions to user to perform operations. As per below example do I have to list all permissions or is there any keyword which will enable all permits? I have copied the example from below link. Thanks in advance.

**link:** https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ovirt/ovirt/ovirt_role_module.html

```
- ovirt.ovirt.ovirt_role:
    name: role
    administrative: true
    permits:
      - manipulate_permissions
      - create_instance
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but as far as I know you need to enable one by one.

For further issues please add them also to GitHub which I check more frequently http://github.com/ovirt/ovirt-ansible-collection